# How many travel options does she have?

Tags: combinatorics

Meredith wants to visit Chicago, New York, Phoenix, San Diego, El Paso, San Antonio, San Jose, and Boston. If she decides to visit some, all, or none of these cities, how many travel options does she have?

Comment: Does **order** of visiting matter?

Comment: @AndreNicolas You would hope so. :P

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the generalized question: Meridith has n cities in mind for possible travel plans. If she decides to visit some, all, or none of these cities, how many travel options does she have?

If the order in which the cities is visited does not matter, then it's simply a question of picking which subset of cities to visit. There are $2^n$ ways to do this.

If the order of visitation does matter. Then we divide it into cases of how many cities she choses to visit.
For all n cities there are $n!$ ways to visit them all.
If she picks k cities out of n, then there are ${n \choose k}$ ways to pick and $k!$ ways to visit them.
Summed over k, the number of cities she chooses to visit, the answer is:

$n! + {n \choose n-1} (n-1)! + {n \choose n-2} (n-2)! + \dots + {n \choose 0}0!$

$=n! + \frac{n!}{(n-1)!1!}(n-1)! + \frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}(n-2)! + \dots + \frac{n!}{0!n!}0!$

$=n! + \frac{n!}{1!} + \frac{n!}{2!} + \dots + \frac{n!}{n!}$

$=n!(1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!})$

For large $n$ this is approximately $e\cdot n!$